# Java ActionListener not picking up button

Tags: java, swing, button, actionlistener

This is the code for the button with the action listener:

```
JButton btnAddChild = new JButton("Add Child");
        btnAddChild.addActionListener(this.controller);
        formPanel.add(btnAddChild);
```

This is the code in my action listener:

```
else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Add Child")){
            System.out.println("Hello");
            try {
                model.addChild(child.getFirstname(), child.getSurname(), child.getDOB(), child.getAddress(),
                        child.getGender(), child.getAllergy(), child.getInfo());
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

For some reason it wont even print the line "Hello" so I know that the action listener isn't being called and I'm not sure why?? Please help :)

Comment: Consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: Where you have implemented your ActionListner ?  If it is on the same class then you should be using  btnAddChild.addActionListener(this) .  Anyway from this code it is not very clear

Comment: `For some reason it wont even print the line "Hello" so I know that the action listener isn't being called` - no you don't know that. All you know is that statement is not being executed. You should have a System.out.println(...) as the first statement of the ActionListener and display the action command. THEN you will know if the ActionListener is called or not. All we know from the posted code is you have a nested if/else statement which may or may not be coded correctly. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
this.controller
```

(not sure exactly how it's being declared or initialized) try creating a brand new action listener as an argument, just to test it out. For example if you defined your action listener as

```
class CustomActionListener implements ActionListener{
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           System.out.println("Hello");
      }
}
```

then you could add the action listener to the button like so

```
btnAddChild.addActionListener(new CustomActionListener());
```

As mentioned in the other answer as well, it could be an issue with your conditional statement. Try placing a print statement very first thing in your action listener.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic exit button with an ActionListener. When you use multiple Listeners you should place the @Override annotation as follows. You can even override the first ActionListener you create.

```
JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Exit");
        cancelButton.setActionCommand("Exit");
        windowPane.add(cancelButton);
        cancelButton.setBounds(0, 0, 1300, 900);
        cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
```